# Insert Only Date and Only time in the table using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to Insert Only Date and Only time in the table(column datatype is DateTime) using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Date and Time are always stored together. The intern representation of it is a number, that represents timeticks that are passed since a certain moment.

You can of course filter the date info and the time info out of it and store it as for example a string.

Or you can make a userdefined type as shown here : http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/31/sql-server-2005-date-time-only-data-types.aspx

Comment: Which is why it was split in SQL Server 2008 into 'date' and 'time' columns.